# Using .bat file for installation/updating programs

Tags: windows, batch-file

Total beginner at batch scripting, i'm trying to make a batch file, checking if a program is running in task manager. If the application is running, run the update file, if the program isn't installed, install the program.. Adobe Reader as an example.

```
@echo off
echo Installing Adobe Reader DC 150072033 Base...
echo This step will be omitted if it is unnecessary.
:B
tasklist | findstr /I "AcroRd32.exe"
if errorlevel 1 (call "msiexec /i AcroRdrDC1502020039.msi /qn") ELSE (timeout /t 30)
GOTO :B
echo.
echo Installing Adobe Reader DC Update Patches...
msiexec /p "AcroRdrUpd1502020039.msp" /qn"
echo.
echo Installation concluded.
```

Hope you have some advise or solutions.
happy new year :)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps next commented code snippet could help:

```
@echo off
echo Installing Adobe Reader DC 150072033 Base...
echo This step will be omitted if it is unnecessary.
:B
rem check if Adobe Reader is currently running not if it's installed
tasklist | findstr /I "AcroRd32.exe"
if errorlevel 1 (
    rem use `start` command instead of `call`
    rem             to ensure that current `bat` waits until `msiexec`'s finish
    start "" /B /WAIT msiexec /i AcroRdrDC1502020039.msi /qn
) ELSE (
    echo please exit Adobe Reader to continue
    timeout /t 30
    rem check again 
    GOTO :B
)
echo.
echo Installing Adobe Reader DC Update Patches...
msiexec /p "AcroRdrUpd1502020039.msp" /qn
echo.
echo Installation concluded.
```

Please note that `tasklist | findstr /I "AcroRd32.exe"` checks if Adobe Reader is currently **running**.  To check if Adobe Reader is **installed**, follow the part [1.7 Identifying deployed applications](http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/files/2012/02/Acrobat_Enterprise_Administration.pdf#page=25) in this document: [Enterprise Administration Guide for the Adobe® Acrobat Family of Products](http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/files/2012/02/Acrobat_Enterprise_Administration.pdf).

In short: check **GUID registry location** , see latter document:

> The GUID is written to a variety of locations. However, Adobe
>   recommends you use the following:
>
> - 32 bit Windows:
>
>   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\{application}\{version}\Installer\`
> - 64 bit Windows:
>
>   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\{application}\{version}\Installer\`

Cf. also this thread: [Check if Adobe Reader is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24008553/3439404)